# How to launch an android app from browser without knowing schema?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

I'm currently working on an application which should launch application from a browser on Android.
I also researched a bit about the intent anchors and tried a few things.

```js
window.open("https://www.youtube.com/"); // works - opens youtube as it is a registered URL for the app
window.open("vnd.youtube:WATCH_ID"); // works - opens youtube with Watchid - schema found in the webs
window.open(
  "intent://#Intent;package=com.google.android.youtube;end"
); // Does not work
```

```html
<a href="intent://#Intent;package=com.google.android.youtube;end">
  TestLink
</a>
<!-- This also does not work -->
```

1. Am I missing something?
2. Is there a way to check for the registered schemas on an Android phone?

Edit:
For my purposes I needed to have the package name (which you can find on the Google Play Store) and the scheme.
To find the scheme on **your** phone for an already **installed** app you can run

```
adb shell "dumpsys package com.package.any.id | grep -i scheme'"
```

and by running

```
adb shell "dumpsys package com.package.any.id"
```

you can also check the intents for the package.

Many thanks

Comment: "Am I missing something?" -- there are many browsers for Android. Different browsers have different rules for how they handle these sorts of requests. Some require users to opt in via a browser settings switch, for example. "Is there a way to check for the registered schemas on an Android phone?" -- I hope not, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: "Different browsers have different rules for how they handle these sorts of requests" -- thanks, I didn't know that!

Comment: As for my second question: I found that I can check the schemes via adb on my phone - which is currently all I need. It also worked fine with the Intent Anchors.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: "I found that I can check the schemes via adb on my phone - which is currently all I need" -- ah, OK. I thought that you were looking to retrieve it directly from JavaScript in a Web page. Glad it is working for you!